# Illustrator: How to exclude textured strokes (Chalkboard effect)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

I'm trying to create a lettering with chalkboard effect in order to print it on a chalkboard mug.
However, most tutorials I found for Adobe Illustrator recommend applying a textured stroke to the text. (One of the charcoal effect brushes)

Now I would like to exclude the stroke (with texture) from the text itself. However, I can't really figure out how to do that without throwing away the charcoal texture as well.

Here's an example: The red part should be excluded from the text. Using a certain color is not an option since we don't know the exact background color and we're only allowed to use 2 colors.

[image: White text with red Charcoal stroke]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your text is *not* live text, but already expanded, or outline created.

1. Select the text objet, and press expand to change it into a group of shapes.
2. Right-click and click on **Ungroup**, or press CTRL + SHIFT + G.
3. Repeat 2 another two times.
4. Carefully select only the red outlines and white text of one letter. Careful! there are some elements left over that might interfere with the following steps.

[image]

5. Press CTRL+SHIFT+F9 to open the **Pathfinder** window, and click on the **Minus Front** button.

You've now finished one letter! Repeat those steps on the rest of letters , and you're done.

Comment: L'il addition: Use the Magic Wand Tool to selct all red objects in one fell swoop.

Comment: @Yokel, You should NOT select all red objects! You must do this one by one, or you will come across problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for! it even worked after merging all the red parts to a compound path and all the white parts to another compound path!

Comment: @ Rosa. Whoa, okay, sorry. I've been doing it that way since the magic wand appeared in Illustrator, and nary a problem if you set your tolerances, but, okay ...

Comment: @Yokel, the magic wand will select **all** the red in the image. It is important to do this **one letter at a time**. if you change the tolerance., magic wand will *not* select the red from all of  the letters at once?